# Why XML parser displays an empty tag differently than written

Tags: xml

Suppose there is an XML file as

```
<xml>
<book>
<name> test </name>
<price>100</price>
**<isbn></isbn>**
</book>
</xml>
```

On opening this file through browser and displays as

```
<xml>
<book>
<name> test </name>
<price>100</price>
**<isbn />**
</book>
</xml>
```

Why parser does this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

`<isbn></isbn>` and `<isbn />` are identically equivalent in XML.

The XML gets parsed to a DOM. Then the DOM is converted back to XML for display. The tool could use either syntax to represent it. The authors picked the empty element syntax.

You'd have to ask them to find out what they were thinking when the made the decision to us empty element syntax instead of start tag/end tag syntax for empty elements. Maybe because it is shorter. Maybe because it emphasize that there are no child nodes. Maybe some other reason.